# What is wrong with this x86 assembly bubble sort program?

Tags: assembly, x86, att

I need to figure out why nothing is swapping in this program. The program obtains an integer array containing 4,5,1,3,2 from a separate C program and it will return it sorted.

I have tried modifying some of the jump commands but nothing has worked.

```
.global myarray

.data
myarray:
    lea (%rdi),%r8      #load array to register
    mov %rsi,%r12       #load array size to register
    mov $0,%r10             #initialize index
sort:
    mov (%r8, %r10, 8), %rax    #store array[i] in rax
    inc %r10            #i++
    mov (%r8, %r10, 8), %rdx    #store array[i+1] in rdx
    cmp %rax, %rdx      #see if rdx is less than rax
    jle swap            #if rdx < rax, swap them
swap:
    cmp %r12, %r10      #check if still in array bounds
    je  check           #if we are at the end, check if sorted
    dec %r10            #i--
    mov %rdx, (%r8, %r10, 8)    #move array[i+1] into array[i]
    inc %r10            #i++
    mov %rax, (%r8, %r10, 8)    #move array[i] into array[i+1]
    jmp     check
check:
    mov $0, %r14        #temporary index in r14
    mov (%r8, %r10, 8), %eax    #temporarily store array[i] in eax
    inc %r14            #i++            
    mov (%r8, %r10, 8), %ebx    #temporarily store array[i+1] in ebx
    cmp %eax, %ebx      #check if ebx is less than eax
    jle sort            #if ebx < eax, swap
    cmp %r12, %r14      #check if still in array bounds
    ret
```

Expected results are the array being returned sorted; 1,2,3,4,5

Comment: `dec/inc` r10 around a memory reference would be much simpler as a displacement as part of the addressing mode:  `-8(%r8, %r10, 8)`.  Simplifying small local parts of your code can make it easier to see the big picture when debugging without getting lost in the clutter.  (Use GDB or whatever other debugger to single-step your code.)

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> mov %rsi,%r12           #load array size to register
> mov $0,%r10             #initialize index
> ```

In an array with 5 elements you can only compare 4 pairs. It would be convenient to decrement `%r12`. At the same time you'll have a way out for when the array has but 1 element:

```
mov %rsi,%r12             #load array size to register
dec %r12
jz  NothingToDo
mov $0,%r10               #initialize index
```

> ```
> cmp %rax, %rdx          #see if rdx is less than rax
> jle swap                #if rdx < rax, swap them
> swap:
> ```

If LessOrEqual the jump goes to *swap*, but else the code falls through in *swap*. That makes no sense!

Below is the code that makes the biggest number bubble to the top.

```
sort:
    mov (%r8, %r10, 8), %rax    #store array[i] in rax
    inc %r10                    #i++
    mov (%r8, %r10, 8), %rdx    #store array[i+1] in rdx
    cmp %rdx, %rax
    jle NoSwap
    dec %r10                    #i--
    mov %rdx, (%r8, %r10, 8)    #move array[i+1] into array[i]
    inc %r10                    #i++
    mov %rax, (%r8, %r10, 8)    #move array[i] into array[i+1]
NoSwap:
    cmp %r12, %r10              #check if still in array bounds
    jb  sort
```

**This inner loop code must be repeated a number of times but each time you lower the limit in `%r12`**. (*)

> ```
> jmp     check
> check:
> ```

This too is a useless `jmp`!

> ```
> check:
> mov $0, %r14        #temporary index in r14
> mov (%r8, %r10, 8), %eax    #temporarily store array[i] in eax
> inc %r14            #i++            
> mov (%r8, %r10, 8), %ebx    #temporarily store array[i+1] in ebx
> cmp %eax, %ebx      #check if ebx is less than eax
> jle sort            #if ebx < eax, swap
> cmp %r12, %r14      #check if still in array bounds
> ```

And this part of the code can not be salvaged. What happens here is beyond comprehension.

---

### (*)

```
    mov     %rdi,%r8
    mov     %rsi,%r12
    dec     %r12
    jz      NothingToDo
OuterLoop:
    mov     $0,%r10
    ...
    dec     %r12
    jnz     OuterLoop
NothingToDo:
    ret
```